# Extracting year from column with date and time in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I have some dataframes that have date and time in the format of YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS so year, month, date a random T for time, and then hours, minutes seconds. Here is another example with actual numbers: 2022-09-17T13:49:52

Ulitimately, I would only like to include data from the years 1993 to present (30 years) and this data frame has data from the 1800s. It will be easy to filter for after with dplyr but my main issue is getting the date column into a format where I can just consider the year for the filter function.

Than you  so much!

Comment: Try this: `as.integer(format(as.Date("2022-09-17T13:49:52"), "%Y"))`

Comment: Use `year` function from `lubridate` or more fun `parse_number()` from `readr`.